# Which aws messaging service to use

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue

I am working on a project where I need to process messages. Now, each message is associated with consumer having unique consumerId. My requirement is that I want all messages for a unique consumerId to be processed one-by-one. i.e. only one consumer should process message for a given consumerId.

Does aws provide any messaging service which fulfils my condition ?

Comment: You can try SQS by configuring `Visibility Timeout` accordingly

Comment: How many consumers are there? If it's a small number, you may want to have each consumer consuming its own SQS queue. Alternatively, you can also use SNS, and have one topic per consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good usage pattern for Amazon Kinesis Data Stream.

A Kinesis Data Stream can be assigned multiple **shards**. Think of each shard as a separate message queue, where each message is kept in order of receipt.

When messages are sent to a Kinesis Data Stream, you provide a **partition key** that is hashed and then used to determine to which shard the message is sent. If you only have one shard, all messages go into that shard. If you have 10 shards, then messages are assigned to up to 10 queues, as long as you have enough variety in the partition keys.

The messages can then be consumed with **your own workers** (eg running on Amazon EC2 instances) or the stream can automatically trigger **AWS Lambda functions**.

Here's where the relevant bit comes in... Your workers (or the Lambda functions) will **process one message at a time from a given shard**. Only when that message has been processed will it pull another message from the same shard. This means that messages from the same `consumerId` (as indicated by the Partition Key) will always be processed in the order they arrived.

Think of it like people being assigned to **queues in a Bank**, where queues are assigned by name (A-K, L-Z). A person will always be sent to the same queue using this method, and each queue will be processed by only one bank teller.

Comment: Thanks John. I will dive into Amazon Kinesis